# Add quotes to list elements

Tags: c#, list, format

How do I append each element in `usersList` and add quotes to each User like so, `"User1","User2","User3"`

```js
class Program {
  
  public static List<string> usersList = new List<string>();
        
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  userList = ["User1,User2,User3"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requires Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

I'm not certain this is what you're looking for, but given a **List** of users like so:

```
List<string> usersList = new List<string> { "User1", "User2", "User3" };
```

You can create a new list of quoted users like so:

```
List<string> quotedList = usersList.Select(u => $"\"{u}\"").ToList();
```

And output them as a comma-delimited list:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", quotedList.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> userList = new List<String>();

String userData = "User1,User2,User3";

userList.AddRange(userData.Split(',').Select(x => String.Format("\"{0}\"", x)));

// check area
for(int i = 0; i < userList.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(userList[i]);
}
```

Comment: This can use some explanations, rather than just code.